# Trouble tying a CCSprite deceleration to the ccTime dt

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, benchmarking

I've got a subclass of CCSprite that knows how to move itself based on two float properties, velX and velY.  I call the subclass's `- (void)update:(ccTime)dt` method from the method of the same name in my game layer.

I use dt to scale how much I move the player and it works great.  I'd like to use dt to scale a deceleration factor to make how the player slows down consistent regardless of how often it's updated.

But it just makes my CCSprite not even show up.

Here's the CCSprite class...

---

```
#import "Player.h"

#define kDeceleration 0.95

@implementation Player

@synthesize velX, velY;

# pragma mark

+ (id)player
{
    Player *player = nil;
    if ((player = [[[super alloc] initWithFile:@"rocket.png"] autorelease])) {
    player.velX = 0.0;
    player.velY = 0.0;
    }
    return player;
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    // move
    self.position = ccp(self.position.x + self.velX * dt, self.position.y + self.velY * dt);
    if (self.position.x < -self.contentSize.width/2) self.position = ccp(winSize.width + self.contentSize.width/2, self.position.y);
    if (self.position.x > winSize.width + self.contentSize.width/2) self.position = ccp(-self.contentSize.width/2, self.position.y);
    if (self.position.y < -self.contentSize.width/2) self.position = ccp(self.position.x, winSize.height + self.contentSize.width/2);
    if (self.position.y > winSize.height + self.contentSize.width/2) self.position = ccp(self.position.x, -self.contentSize.width/2);

    // decelerate
    self.velX *= kDeceleration * 0.0165 / dt; // works if the line is: self.velX *= kDeceleration;
    if (fabs(self.velX) < 1.0) self.velX = 0.0;
    self.velY *= kDeceleration * 0.0165 / dt; // works if the line is: self.velY *= kDeceleration;
    if (fabs(self.velY) < 1.0) self.velY = 0.0;

}

- (void)draw
{
    [super draw];
    glLineWidth(1);
    ccDrawCircle(ccp(self.contentSize.width/2, self.contentSize.height/2), 3*self.contentSize.width/4, CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360), 60, NO);
}

@end
```

---

The problem is in the `// decelerate` section.  If I leave out the `* 0.0165 / dt` part of the two lines that decelerate the player, it works, but it's way faster on the phone than the simulator due to framerate differences.  This should scale it, but it just screws it up.

I've tried all kinds of NSLogging and if I use dt at all, I get `nan` for the value of my velX and velY properties.

Could it have something to do with using the method name `-update?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this formula instead:

```
float decelerator = pow(kDeceleration, 60 * dt);
self.velX *= decelerator;
self.velY *= decelerator;
```

The logic behind the math:

Suppose the framerate on simulator is at 30fps compared to the normal 60fps on device. Thus, for every frame on simulator, the device already shows 2 frames. Thus every call on the `update` on simulator should give the same result for 2 calls on device. After two calls on device, `self.velX` has been multiplied by `kDeceleration` two times, meaning the new value is equal to `self.velX * kDeceleration * kDeceleration`. By same logic, if the framerate on simulator is 1/3 of that on device, the new value is `self.velX * kDeceleration * kDeceleration * kDeceleration`. Thus, we can generalize it as `self.velX * pow(kDeceleration, n)` where n is the number of times the `update` method to be called to catch up with framerate of 60fps, which is `60 * dt`.

Comment: thanks again!  Works like a charm. That was what I was trying to do. Any idea why mine didn't work?  BTW, I work in Senai sometimes - are you near there?

Comment: @Steve yours didn't work because the math is wrong. it would have worked if it was `self.velX -= kDeceleration * 0.0165 / dt` but with multiplication to result, you need to use exponential .. p/s: I'm in the capital city Kuala Lumpur, which is like 6 hours drive from Senai :P